# Marginalizing a time-series model in Stan

Tags: time-series, bayesian, hidden-markov-model, stan

I'm trying to implement the following model in Stan

---

$$
\theta[i] \thicksim Normal(0,1) \\ b[k] \thicksim Uniform(0.0, 2.5) \\ a[k] \thicksim Normal(0,1) \\ guess[k] \thicksim Uniform(0.0, 0.5) \\ learn[k] \thicksim Beta(1, 1) \\ ss[k] \thicksim Uniform(0.5, 1.0)
$$
For simplicity, I will refer

$$
\alpha[i,k,t] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} \alpha^{(t)} \\
y[i,k,t] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} y^{(t)} \\
ss[k] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} ss \\
g[k] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} g \\
learn[k] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} learn \\ 
\theta[i] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} \theta \\
value[i,k], a[k], b[k] \hspace{1cm} as \hspace{1cm} value, a, b
$$

---

$$
value = Sigmoid(1.7 * a * (\theta - b))\\
{Pr(\alpha^{(1)} | \theta, a, b)}  \thicksim Bernoulli(value) \\
Pr(\alpha^{(t)} | \alpha^{(t-1)}, learn) \thicksim Bernoulli(\alpha^{(t-1)} == 1 ? 1.0 : learn) \\
Pr(y^{(t)} | ss, g, \alpha^{(t)}) \thicksim Bernoulli(ss[k]^{\alpha^{(t)}} * g[k]^{1-\alpha^{(t)}})
$$

---

where t runs from **1 to T**, i runs from **1 to N** and k runs from **1 to K**.

Since Stan does not support discrete latent parameters, I need to marginalize these parameters. Since Y depends on ss, g and alpha, I think I need to only marginalize these "alpha"s.

The PMFs of y and alpha's are as follows:

$$
Pr(y^{(t)}|ss,g,\alpha^{(t)}) = {(ss[k]^{\alpha^{(t)}} * g[k]^{1-\alpha^{(t)}})}^{y^{(t)}} * {(1 - ss[k]^{\alpha^{(t)}} * g[k]^{1-\alpha^{(t)}})}^{1-y^{(t)}} \\
{Pr(\alpha^{(1)} | \theta, a, b)}  = (1-value)^{1-\alpha^{(1)}} * value^{\alpha^{(1)}} \\
{Pr(\alpha^{(t)} | \alpha^{(t-1)}, learn)}  = learn^{1-\alpha^{(t-1)}}
$$

My attempt to marginalize over α is as follows:

$$
P( y^{(1)} | ss, g, \theta, a, b) = \sum_{\alpha^{(1)}=0,1} Pr(y^{(1)} | ss, g, \alpha^{(1)}) Pr(\alpha^{(1)} | \theta, a, b) \\
t>1 \\
P( y^{(t)} | ss, g, learn, \theta, a, b) = \sum_{\alpha^{(1)}=0,1} [P(y^{(t)} | ss, g, learn, \alpha^{(1)}) * P(\alpha^{(1)} | \theta, a, b)] \\
= \sum_{\alpha^{(1)}=0,1} [\sum_{\alpha^{(t)}=0,1}[P(y^{(t)} | ss, g, \alpha^{(t)}) * P(\alpha^{(t)} | \alpha^{(1)}, learn)] * P(\alpha^{(1)} | \theta, a, b)]
$$

These equations later reduced to:

$$
P( y^{(1)} | ss, g, \theta, a, b) = G + value * (S - G)\\
P( y^{(t)} | ss, g, learn, \theta, a, b) = (G-S)(1-learn)^t(1-value) + S \\
where; G = g^{y^{(t)}} * (1 - g)^{1 - y^{(t)}} \\
S = ss^{y^{(t)}} * (1 - ss)^{1 - y^{(t)}} \\
value = Sigmoid(1.7 * a * (\theta - b))\\
$$

Does this derivation seem correct or am I going wrong somewhere? Since, I am new to stan, I would also like to get this clarified: I would need to define a stan function like `real bernoulli_lpmf` where I have a  `vector[T] out` with `out[1] = logprob(y^(1) | ss,g,θ,a,b)` and  `out[t] = logprob(y^(1) | ss,g,learn,θ,a,b)`? Later, I would need to `return(sum(out))` to get my stan model running. Is this the proper "stan" way to do this or is there a more efficient way (since I need to fit for very large data)?

Any comments on whether or not this is valid would be really helpful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried the Stan forums? You might get help more quickly over there for Stan-specific questions. https://discourse.mc-stan.org/

Comment: Yeah sure, but I was also wondering if my method of marginalizing was correct